# how to install linux with windows 10 in the same disk

Tags: linux, windows-10, fedora

I'm a windows user, and I want to install Linux with my windows 10 on the same hard disk. my HDD has 2Tb so I take 30Gb to install fedora but after making the live USB and go to the installation I see only one partition that is all the disk (2 Tb ) which means I'm going to lose my windows and all my files[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcVII.png)

Comment: Are you keeping UEFI mode enabled, or following out dated instructions, that specify to enable Legacy or CSM?

Comment: where I  can enable the UEFI when I make the Live USB drive ??? sorry if I don't understand I don't know so much about this keyword

Comment: Many modern Linux distros will take care of creating a new partition (with your guidance). If you've create a new partition, do not create a file system (leave it unformatted). Also, when you *created* the 30 GB partition, did you*commit* or *apply* changes? Most disk management tools require that second step to allow time to rethink.

Comment: I verify the 30 Gb is still unallocated

Comment: I am not suggesting you enable it, I am suggesting you verify, it’s enabled.  Cannot even begin to answer your question without that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to convert the disk from Dynamic to Basic to install Fedora.

Dynamic disks use Logical Disk Manager to manage virtual partitions. As far as Fedora is concerned, there's only one 2TB partition on your disk.